# Kendo Angular Switch Width?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI for Angular 11.  I am using switches in a couple places but they don't look like the example ones.  Here are mine:

[image: My Switches]

Here are the default ones shown on the Telerik website:

[image: Example Switch]

As you can see the proportions are quite different, mine are much longer and thinner; I would rather have the proportions of the default.  I've been over and over it and for the life of me I can't find the style that is defining this...  I can set the width to smaller and the overall item gets smaller but the white dot that indicates on off state then goes off the right side of the control and gets partially or fully hidden depending on the width I set.

Can anyone point me to the right place to change this around?  It would be much appreciated if you could...

**EDIT**

I'm not entirely sure what code to show.  My HTML just looks like this:

```
<kendo-switch [(ngModel)]="role.Map"
              [disabled]="role.Sync"
              (click)="OnRoleMapUpdated(role)">Map
</kendo-switch>
```

As far as styles I have this in my main styles:

```
.k-switch{
   width: 75px;
}
```

Changing that is how I change the width of the component but if it gets smaller than this it starts obscuring the white circle portion.

The other styles are from a generated pre-compiled css file from the Kendo theme generator.  It's about 13,000 lines long but here are the styles that reference the text 'switch' in any way:

```
.k-switch {
  border-radius: 5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*width: 5em;*/
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: left; }
  .k-switch [type='checkbox'] {
    display: none; }

.k-switch,
.k-switch-container,
.k-switch-handle {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.k-switch-container {
  border-radius: 5em;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-out 0s; }

.k-switch-handle {
  border-radius: 5em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 200ms ease-out 0s; }
  .k-ie .k-switch-handle {
    display: block; }

.k-switch-on .k-switch-handle {
  left: calc(100% - 2em); }
  .k-ie .k-switch-on .k-switch-handle,
  .k-edge .k-switch-on .k-switch-handle {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -2em; }

.k-switch-off .k-switch-handle {
  left: 0; }

.k-switch-label-on,
.k-switch-label-off {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% + calc( -2em + -13px));
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  line-height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden; }

.k-switch-label-on {
  text-align: left;
  left: 8px; }

.k-switch-label-off {
  text-align: right;
  right: 8px; }

.k-rtl .k-switch.k-switch-on .k-switch-handle,
.k-switch[dir="rtl"].k-switch-on .k-switch-handle {
  left: 0; }

.k-rtl .k-switch.k-switch-off .k-switch-handle,
.k-switch[dir="rtl"].k-switch-off .k-switch-handle {
  left: calc(100% - 2em); }

.k-rtl .k-switch .k-switch-label-on,
.k-switch[dir="rtl"] .k-switch-label-on {
  text-align: right;
  left: initial;
  right: 8px; }

.k-rtl .k-switch .k-switch-label-off,
.k-switch[dir="rtl"] .k-switch-label-off {
  text-align: left;
  left: 8px;
  right: initial; }

.k-switch-handle {
  background-clip: padding-box; }
  .k-ie11 .k-switch-handle,
  .k-edge12 .k-switch-handle,
  .k-edge13 .k-switch-handle {
    background-clip: border-box; }

.k-switch-label-on,
.k-switch-label-off {
  text-shadow: none; }

.k-switch-on .k-switch-container {
  color: white;
  background-color: #731717; }

.k-switch-on .k-switch-handle {
  color: white;
  background-color: white; }

.k-switch-on:focus, .k-switch-on.k-state-focused {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #b68686; }

.k-switch-on:hover .k-switch-container, .k-switch-on.k-state-hover .k-switch-container {
  color: white;
  background-color: #531111; }

.k-switch-on:hover .k-switch-handle, .k-switch-on.k-state-hover .k-switch-handle {
  color: white;
  background-color: white; }

.k-switch-on .k-switch-label-off {
  color: transparent; }

.k-switch-off .k-switch-container {
  color: black;
  background-color: #e4e7eb; }

.k-switch-off .k-switch-handle {
  color: black;
  background-color: white; }

.k-switch-off:focus, .k-switch-off.k-state-focused {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #f1f3f5; }

.k-switch-off:hover .k-switch-container, .k-switch-off.k-state-hover .k-switch-container {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ced3db; }

.k-switch-off:hover .k-switch-handle, .k-switch-off.k-state-hover .k-switch-handle {
  color: black;
  background-color: white; }

.k-switch-off .k-switch-label-on {
  color: transparent; }

.k-switch {
  box-shadow: none; }
  .k-switch:focus .k-switch-container, .k-switch.k-state-focused .k-switch-container {
    outline: none; }
  .k-switch.k-state-disabled {
    cursor: default; }
  .k-switch[aria-readonly="true"] {
    pointer-events: none; }
```

On the main `.k-switch` style I did try to comment out the width property but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Part of the problem is not sure where to look but I posted as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Kendo style variables.
Let's say you put something like the code below into a file named 'variables.scss'.

```
$kendo-switch-label-display: block;
$kendo-switch-sizes: (
  sm: (
    font-size: 14px,
    track-width: 90px,
    track-height: 40px,
    thumb-width: 50px,
    thumb-height: 36px,
    thumb-offset: 2px,
    label-offset: 10px,
  ),
  md: (
    font-size: 14px,
    track-width: 90px,
    track-height: 40px,
    thumb-width: 50px,
    thumb-height: 36px,
    thumb-offset: 2px,
    label-offset: 10px,
  ),
  lg: (
    font-size: 14px,
    track-width: 90px,
    track-height: 40px,
    thumb-width: 50px,
    thumb-height: 36px,
    thumb-offset: 2px,
    label-offset: 10px,
  ),
);
$kendo-switch-off-track-text: black;
$kendo-switch-on-track-text: white;
```

After that you add

```
@import './kendo-custom-theme/variables.scss';
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.scss';
```

to the main styles.scss file and your settings should be applied.